# SwiftUI: How to navigate from UIViewRepresentable to SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using [KVKCalendar](https://github.com/kvyatkovskys/KVKCalendar) on my SwiftUI application. I connected the UIKit library with bridge class called UIViewRepresntable. In this class, i override function which looks like:

```
func didSelectEvent(_ event: Event, type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?){
    // in this function i would like to redirect to SwiftUI View called EventDetailScreen(event.ID)
}
```

Also i added `weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?` in the top of Coordinator class so the whole class CalendarDisplayView, the bridge:

```
import SwiftUI
import EventKit
struct CalendarDisplayView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var events: [Event]
  @Binding var updatedDate: Date?
  private var calendar = CalendarView(frame: .zero)
  var selectDate = Date()
  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CalendarDisplayView>) -> CalendarView {
    calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
    calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
    calendar.reloadData()
    return calendar
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: CalendarView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CalendarDisplayView>) {
    context.coordinator.events = events
    calendar.reloadData()
  }
  func makeCoordinator() -> CalendarDisplayView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
  public init(events: Binding<[Event]>, updatedDate: Binding<Date?>) {
      self._events = events
      var style = Style()
      self._updatedDate = updatedDate
      selectDate = Date()
      var frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
      frame.origin.y = 0
      frame.size.height -= 160
      calendar = CalendarView(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
  // MARK: Calendar DataSource and Delegate
  class Coordinator: NSObject, CalendarDataSource, CalendarDelegate {
    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController? //Added it by myself
    func eventsForCalendar(systemEvents: [EKEvent]) -> [Event] {
      return events
    }
    private var view: CalendarDisplayView
    var events: [Event] = [] {
      didSet {
        view.calendar.reloadData()
      }
    }
    var type: CalendarType = .day {
      didSet {
        view.calendar.set(type: type, date: view.selectDate)
        view.calendar.reloadData()
      }
    }
    var updatedDate: Date? {
       didSet {
         if let date = updatedDate {
           view.selectDate = date
           view.calendar.reloadData()
         }
       }
     }
    init(_ view: CalendarDisplayView) {
      self.view = view
      super.init()
    }
    func didSelectDates(_ dates: [Date], type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?) {
      updatedDate = dates.first ?? Date()
    }
    func didSelectEvent(_ event: Event, type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?) {
      // PROBLEM
    }
  }
}
```

CalendarScreen SwiftUI View

```
import SwiftUI
struct CalendarScreen: View {
    @State private var typeCalendar = CalendarType.day
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    @State private var updatedDate: Date?
  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        CalendarDisplayView(events: $events, updatedDate: $updatedDate)
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
      }
    }.onAppear{
      viewModel.fetchCalendarEvents()
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
  }
}
```

I tried to create NavigationLink in function but it cant have return, because this is function that i override from KVKCalendar library.

```
func didSelectEvent(_ event: Event, type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?){
    NavigationLink(destination: EventDetailScreen(event.ID))
}
```

Moreover i tried to attach UIHostingController but didnt work aswell.

```
func didSelectEvent(_ event: Event, type: CalendarType, frame: CGRect?){
    let screen = UIHostingController(rootView: EventDetailScreen(event.ID))
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(screen, animated: true)
}
```

I was trying to search how to change view from UIView class to SwiftUI view class but without proper result. Probably, it was wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found an answer by adding an extension CalendarDisplayView

```
extension UIView {
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder?.next
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

and adding code in didSelectEvent

```
view.calendar.parentViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(EventDetialScreen(event.ID), animated: true)
```